# Angular.js default selected doesn't work with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The `selected` tag will not work because ng-model depends on ng-selected, how can I hardcode `One` as my default selection here?

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select ng-model="selectedPerson">
          <option  selected value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the "selected" from your view

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select ng-model="selectedPerson">
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>


    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Inside your controller, simply do the  following :

```
$scope.selectedPerson = '1';
```

Comment: this doesn't work, have to use `$scope.selectedPerson = '1'`